# Number of ways of selecting $n$ things out of $3n$ things, of which $n$ are of one kind alike, $n$ of second type are alike, and rest are different

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways of selection of $n$ things out of $3n$ things of which $n$ are of one kind alike and $n$ are of second type alike and rest are different:
Options are

A) $n2^{n-1}$

B) $(n+2)2^{n-1}$

I want a detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by JMoravitz answers your question and offers a clean solution. The following should be an alternative proof; it's not super detailed unfortunately, sorry about that.

Consider the problem of selecting $n$ things out of $2n$ things of which $n$ are of one kind alike (say $n$ A's) and the rest are different (say $1,2,3,...,n$).
If you pick one of such combinations and then delete all the A's you get a subset of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$; in fact, it should be easy to proof that this is a bijection. The number of all possible subsets of $\{1,2,3,...n\}$ is $2^n$ (for each number in {1,2,3,...,n} you have two possibilities: either include it in your subset or not) so this is the answer.

The idea is to generalize this approach to your problem. Before, we had a subset $S$ of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ and then we labelled all numbers which are not in $S$ as A's . Now, we are going to pick a subset $S$ and fix a number $j$; each number which is not in $S$ is going to be labelled A if it is less or equal to $j$ and B if it is strictly greater than $j$.

So say we want to select a set $L$ of $n$ things out of $n$ A's, $n$ B's and $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$.
Pick a number $j\in\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ (there are $n$ possibilities) and a subset $S$ of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ which does not contain $j$ (for fixed $j$ there are $2^{n-1}$ possibilities). There are $n2^{n-1}$ possibilities in total. $(*)$

Suppose now $j,S$ are fixed; we are going to construct $L$.
First, put all elements of $S$ in $L$.
Put an A in $L$ for each number in $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ which is not in $S$ and which is less or equal to $j$.
(since $j$ is not in $S$ and $j\leq j$ we always get at least one $A$)
Similarly, put a B in $L$ for each number in $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ which is not in $S$ and which is strictly greater than $j$.
Note that the number of A's and B's is equal to $n-|S|$, so indeed $L$ is a set of $n$ object.

This defines a bijection between all $n2^{n-1}$ possibilities and all subsets $L$ which contain at least one A. (I did not proved it here but I am positive it's true)

Now we just miss the combinations which do not contain any A; but this is equivalent to the easier case in $(*)$, so we know that these missing combinations are $2^{n}$.

The final answer is then $n2^{n-1}+2^n=(n+2)2^{n-1}$.